# Page numbering in Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

How do get the 'Page 1 of 3' to ignore the title page?

I've managed to get the current page number to ignore it but not the total number of pages.

Answer (score 3):

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/remove-the-page-number-from-the-first-page-HP001227657.aspx

see botom of page to start without counting the first page and use {={NUMPAGES}-1} to get a page count 1 shy of the total.

Page {PAGE} of {={NUMPAGES}-1}

**to insert the braces** (you can't just type them) you press [ctrl] F9

to toggle view to see the values press: [alt] F9

http://word.mvps.org/faqs/numbering/pagenumbering.htm